# Как забиндить сервис в повторяющейся задаче?

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarm-manager, android-data-binding, android-binder

В своём приложения я использую Work Manager для выполнения определённых задач. Логика работы такая: На устройство приходит push(с периодичностью 5 минут). Он в свою очередь запускает одноразовый work. В work исходя из пуша выполняются 3 действия. Это запуск сервиса, запуск аларм менеджера, и остановка сервиса. В doWork у меня биндится сервис с нулевым флагом. Допустим пришло у меня 20 пушей, соответственно 20 подписчиков на бинд. И когда я хочу их отбиндить и остановить сервис, onServiceDisconect сработает 20 раз. Бинд мне необходим для получения некоторых параметров с сервиса. Сервис работает в форграунде. Могу ли я получить доступ к свойствам сервиса и не биндить его повторно при выполнении ворка? Если нет, то как выйти из положения? Прошу навести на мысль.

```
public Result doWork() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    login = sharedPreferences.getString("Login", "");
        intent = new Intent(context, GpsService.class);
        context.bindService(intent, connection, 0);
    if(action.equals("onStart")) {
        context.startService(intent);
    }
        return Result.success();
}
private final ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        GpsService.LocalBinder binder = (GpsService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        if(mService.locations!=null)
        ..........SomeMthods.............
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
        if(action.equals("onStop")) {
            alarmManager.cancel(pi);
            mService.StopUpdates();
            context.unbindService(connection);
            context.stopService(intent);
        }
        else if(action.equals("")){
            alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 1000 * 4), pi), pi);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        CreateNotification("Stop!");
    }
};
```

В сервисе:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам сервис? делайте всю работу в doWork. Если требуется длительное выполнение, то https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running с аналогичным foreground уведомлением.

Comment: В сервисе я gps координаты получаю. До этого пытался делать всё в ворке. Вызывал обновление координат, но они не обновлялись, а просто дублировались. Поэтому решил через сервис делать. Ок, попробую через длительный ворк реализовать. Спасибо!)

Comment: Так же до этого была проблема проблема китайфонами. На них запускал work. Они при переходя в дозу благополучно задачу сливали. Поэтому пришлось прибегнуть к fcm. Может быть при реализации длительного ворка можно будет обойтись без fcm?

Comment: Реализовал foregroundinfo. Но он как только задача выполняется сбрасывается. В доках пишут о задачах которые выполняются более 10 минут. Моя же задача занимает секунды 2-3. Но мне важно чтобы координаты отправлялись новые. И обновлялись даже в дозе.

Comment: А зачем вы отвязываете сервис все время?

Comment: Хм, в коде выше он только бандится. Отвзяка происходит по параметру из пуша. onStop придёт только 1 раз ж.

Comment: А нельзя 1 раз забиндить сервис и не отвязывать его (даже при `stop`)?

Comment: Ну, забиндить 1 раз можно. Не отвязаться вовсе?? А как мне тогда остановить сервис. Просто стопсервис вызывать? Так же не совсем понимаю как мне данные с сервиса брать. Ведь ворк менеджер вернул суксесс, и из памяти очистился. Задача то одноразовая.

Comment: Вы можете подождать в locationUpdates чтоб пришли новые координаты, а пока не пришли, висеть в ожидании (CountDownLatch повесить), и вообще если происходит выход из doze, то координаты могут не обновиться довольно долго, при этом слать старые, особенно если у вас fused provider и нет например каких-то гуглокарт, которые координаты собирают...

Comment: Делал с латчем. Возникала такая проблема что срабатывает latch.await, а до latch.countdown не доходит. И соответственно весь ворк виснет так как не было result.success...

Comment: Так же не совсем понятно следующее. Реализовал ForegroundInfo, вызываю сначала его, создаю уведомление. Затем запускаю метод для получения координат. Но ещё до получения координат срабатывает result.success и foregroundinfo завершается. Хотя колл бэк ещё не вернул мне координаты. В документации сказано что главное сначала запустить foregroundinfo, а затем метод который будет долго работать. А на деле выходит иначе

Comment: Все правильно, вы должны ожидать координаты, после получения сделать latch.countdown() и тогда doWork уже вернет success. А пока он не завершился будет отображаться уведомление. Получение координат должно происходить в другом потоке (в зависимости от того каким апи вы пользуетесь есть разные варианты подписки на координаты), проверьте, чтобы doWork выполнялся в фоне (по дефолту так), а координаты приходили, например, в main. тогда countdown замечательно вызовется и ваш воркер закончит работу. И по хорошему latch надо ставить с timeout'ом.

Comment: Возникла проблема с китайцами, может час не получать координаты, а потом резко штук 20 выгрузить... На самсунге не наблюдается такого. Если использую отдельный фоновый сервис, то коорды стабильно раз в 5 минут. На китайце максимально в настройках всё сделал. Энергосбережение, контроль активности и автозапуск.